# Make gif transapernt on tkinter canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, gif

I have the below code to show my animated gif on a canvas but even though the gif has a transpert bg, it get in a white background. is there a way to remove it?

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from itertools import cycle

DELAY = 20

def animate():
    canvas.itemconfig(img,image=next(frames_cycle))
    root.after(DELAY,animate)

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('300x300')
root.config(background='red')

frames = []
im = Image.open('loading_circle.gif')
for frame in range(im.n_frames):
    im.seek(frame)
    frames.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(im.convert('RGBA')))
frames_cycle=cycle(frames)

canvas = tk.Canvas(root,bg='red', width=300, height=300)
img = canvas.create_image(120,0,anchor='nw',image=next(frames_cycle))
canvas.pack()
animate()
root.resizable(False, False)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your code works fine (i.e. I can see the red background) with my sample transparent GIF image.  It may be issue on your GIF image, try changing `im.copy()` to `im.convert('RGBA')`.

Comment: Please avoid editing the code in the question to make it work properly.